# Log “Warning” instead of “Error” with stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I use `new Error()` or `new TypeError()` I am going to get something that looks like this for a stacktrace:

```
Error: Live-Mutex client lock request timed out after 6000ms
```

I am wondering if there is a way to generate a message that starts with "Warning:" instead of "Error:".

I don't think JS offers us `new Warning()` but I am looking for something like that.

Ultimately, I am looking to pair it with `process.emit('warning')` like so:

```
process.emit('warning', new Warning('foo bar baz'));
```

I need to have a stack trace available.

Comment: You mean like `console.warn('Warning!');`?

Comment: `console.trace()` for all modern browsers

Comment: Is this achievable with [process.emitWarning](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_emitwarning_warning_type_code_ctor) by passing your warning string as the first parameter instead of the Error object?

Comment: yeah probably, I didn't know about `process.emitWarning`

Comment: @faintsignal yeah that seems like the best answer, please add that thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer accordingly. Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will be able to achieve your goal by using [process.emitWarning](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_emitwarning_warning_type_code_ctor).

Its first parameter can be either an Error object or simply a string containing your warning message. You may need to use the other parameters to tweak the result if it doesn't immediately meet the needs of your context.

Disclaimer: I have not used this function before. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: this is for a library, I need to use `process.emit('warning')` so the end user can handle the logging their way